# How to split array key and value in sperate keys and values

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a useable array. 
This is what I did to get the following array from my .csv file.

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
    $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
});
array_shift($csv);
```

Right now I've got an array with these keys and values:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Label;Account;Registered;Licensed;User;UserLicense] => Test;Test;No;No;test;no;
    )
```

And I want to get an array like:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Label] => Test
        [Account] => Test
        [Registered] => No
        [Licensed] => No
        [User] => test
        [UsreLicense] => no
    )
```

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far? also, the construct of your array looks weird.  An array as a key?

Comment: Got it from a .csv file, I'll edit my question

Comment: If you get it from a CSV file, you should build the right structure when you read the file using `freadcsv()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

```
class arrCsv {

        private $arr;

        private function getValFromArray($item, $key) {
            $arrKeys = explode(';', $key);
            $arrVal = explode(';', $item);
            array_pop($arrVal); // remove last empty item

            $this->arr[] = array_combine($arrKeys, $arrVal);

        }

        function setNewArr($arItems) {
            array_walk_recursive($arItems, array($this, 'getValFromArray'));
        }

        function getNewArr() {
            return $this->arr;
        }

    }

    $r = new arrCsv;
    $r->setNewArr($csvArray);

    $vals = $r->getNewArr();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found:

```
$usersCsv = array();
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
  $usersCsv[] = $data;
  array_walk($usersCsv, function(&$a) use ($usersCsv) {
       $a = array_combine($usersCsv[0], $a);
      });
    }
 fclose($handle);
 array_splice($usersCsv, 0, 1);
}
```

Thanks for the help anyways!